# Good HTML editor/viewer for Windows that allows GUI DOM manipulation

Tags: html, editor

I am looking for a HTML editor/viewer for Windows that will allow me to open an existing HTML file and remove and move around elements of the DOM (divs, tds, etc), preferably in a graphical tree structure. If not that then at least it will let me know when my tweaks have broken the DOM (for example warning unclosed span).

Can you give me the link to download such a tool? Free is better.

Answer (score 0):

You should try Dreamweaver and download the trial version to check your requirements. If its fine for you purchase accordingly. Download link- http://www.adobe.com/in/products/dreamweaver.html